# Is it possible to catch an output from command line app continuously for parsing output line by line, using Linux Bash

Tags: bash

Can't find such a solution in Bash.
For instance:
need to write a bash script, where we start a ping app, that gives a continuous output:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=15.8 ms
...
```

Can we get each line for further parsing data?
Like write ping output to some kind of buffer, then in a loop read from it each T(timeout).
So in total, i need to read all those `"64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq..."` until i stop execution.

I will be thankful if someone may point me to a solution, or say if it is possible at all))
Thanks!

Comment: Bash is not something Linux-specific, FYI. That said, it has a `read` builtin that you could use here.

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do ...; done`

Comment: Pipe the output of this program into the program which is supposed to process it. That's what pipes have been invented for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want should be possible in **Bash**.

We can start the ping in the background and redirect its output to a file descriptor.

We  can then use **Bash** builtin `read` in a while loop to read from that file descriptor every after duration **T**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Start the ping command in the background and redirect its output to a file descriptor
exec 3< <(ping -i 1 8.8.8.8)  

# Duration T in the question for waiting to read in seconds
# see (sleep 1)
T=5

# Loop to continuously read and process each line from the file descriptor
while read -u 3 line; do
    echo "Processing line: $line"
    sleep $T
done

# Close the file descriptor when done
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: Good use of an alternate descriptor, you should add the `-r` option to `read` to prevent the backslash acting as an escape character (you should to this for all read in bash). Also, there is no need for `sleep $T`, `read` will simply block waiting for input and read data when it is available. All adding `sleep` does is back that process up by injecting delay. All that said, from a fundamental standpoint -- you have a good approach.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are right about the `-r` I forgot that but recall the ping outputs continuously and input is almost always available, but the user might want to only process it after a duration. I figured it should be necessary.

Comment: Yes, for a specific duration, you don't want `sleep`. You want to keep track of elapsed time and continue reading. For example `start="$(date +'%s')"` before you enter your read-loop and after each read check `now="$(date +'%s')"; if [$((now - start)) -gt "$T"]; then # do whatever; start="$(date +'%s')"; fi`. That way you `# do whatever` is needed each `$T` seconds without suspending the process with `sleep` ... `:)`

Comment: If you want to go nuts on elapsed-time precision, you can use *nanoseconds* as well, e.g. `date +'%s.%N'` ... `:)` Though at that point, you would need to use a timeout on the `read` as the slow output of `ping` would likely be much, much greater than your elapsed-time increment. `+'%s'` is good enough...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You do have a point. The need need for suspending the process or not all depends on what it is being used for. Although no such information was provided in the question.

Comment: That solution works "like a Boss" for me!)
And solution of @Ashok also very nice and tiny. I'll save it to my knowledge base)) 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

your_command="your_command_here"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Process each line as you like
    echo "Processing line: $line"
    # Add your parsing logic here
done < <($your_command)
```

Replace `your_command_here` with the actual command you want to run. The `echo "Processing line: $line"` is just an example; you can replace it with your own parsing or processing logic.

**Note:** The while read loop will continue until the command finishes, so if the command runs indefinitely, you might need additional logic to control the loop or run it in the background

Comment: I feel like this approach of storing the output in a string would not be appropriate if the command that outputs needs to continue running as we get input from it

Comment: @Jore That's not a problem here; using `... done < <(command)` works a lot like a pipe, but with the `while` loop running in the main shell process (rather than a subshell like putting it in a pipe would do).

Comment: Thank you! Your template is actually very useful and it works, but partly. For the ping app as was in my question, it is great and i will use this for sure! But the 'ping' was as example, and i use another (private) app, where it does not work if i pass additional arguments, where my app gives an output to STDOUT and also writes output to a file.
Thank you once more!

Comment: I'd recommend against storing the command in a variable (see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). Just use the command directly, e.g.`... done < <(ping 8.8.8.8)`.

Comment: Storing the command in a variable is a waste of memory at best, and a syntax error at worst. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050